# Run a laptop while closed without monitor

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, sleep

I can not for the life of me figure out how to keep a laptop running (i.e. not go into sleep mode) while the lid is closed. The menu in power options leaves the machine on but only when there is an external monitor connected.

How can I leave my machine on and running while the lid is closed and without an external monitor? I'd be okay with leaving the display on, but I can't seem to disable the ACPI Switch that detects open/closed states.

Comment: Have you reviewed Event Viewer to determine what the system is actually doing, or not doing, when the lid is closed?  The only thing I'm aware of that would prevent an option set via Power Options is a Group Policy or other Admin level change (power options would then display a greyed out message similar to _"options being managed by an administrator"_).  Have you reviewed any of the diagnostic output from `powercfg` _(to see possible diagnostics: `powercfg /?`, which will be saved in `%UserProfile%`)_

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's going into sleep mode?

Expected behavior is that you set "Do Nothing" in power plan for the action on when close lid, (make sure to do it for main/battery as appropriate) and it does nothing except cutting the power to the screen's back-light.

When you re-open the lid after a few seconds, does it lock your session? (If it doesn't, assuming you have a password login, it didn't sleep).